# How can I create a 3d game in p5.js. Camera positions?

Tags: camera, p5.js

I want to develop a 3d game, I just want the camera to move with my character which is a 3d model(.obj). Is there any way we could make the camera move like that. Also explain me about WEBGL in p5.js. I want to make a first person game with p5. Is there any library for camera to be added? In my game there is a first stage which is a 3d infinite runner game, and the second phase should work like fps game. please help me out solve my problem. thank you in advance.

Comment: There is the built-in command `camera()` https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/camera and a built-in object `camera` https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Camera, both of which can do what it seems that you are looking for.

Comment: When asking questions on StackOverflow you should try to be focused and specific. This question has too many different threads and is too general. For example "explain me about WEBGL" is way too broad a question for a StackOverflow question. You need to do some background research before you start asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

As jstl pointed out, p5.js has built-in capabilities for creating and manipulating [cameras](https://p5js.org/reference/#group-Lights,%20Camera).

Here is a basic example of FPS style mouselook and keyboard movement:

```js
const skyBoxColors = [
  'lightcoral',
  'green',
  'goldenrod',
  'mediumblue',
  'skyblue',
  'saddlebrown'
];

const skyBoxSize = 2000;

let cam;
let skyBoxGraphics;
let skyBoxDirections;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  noStroke();
  cam = createCamera();
  cam.move(0, -50, 0);
}

const speed = 2;
const mouseSensitivity = 0.1;

function draw() {
  if (mouseCaptured) {
    if (keyIsDown(27)) {
      mouseCaptured = false;
      exitPointerLock();
    }

    cam.pan(-movedX * mouseSensitivity);
    cam.tilt(movedY * mouseSensitivity);
    cam.move(
      // D - right, A - left 
      (keyIsDown(68) ? speed : 0) + (keyIsDown(65) ? -speed : 0),
      // Q - down, E - up
      (keyIsDown(81) ? speed : 0) + (keyIsDown(69) ? -speed : 0),
      // S - backward, W - forward
      (keyIsDown(83) ? speed : 0) + (keyIsDown(87) ? -speed : 0)
    );
  }

  debugMode();
  drawSkyBox();

  ambientLight(50, 50, 50);
  directionalLight(200, 200, 200, 0.5, 0.75, -1);

  fill('teal');
  box(100);
}

let mouseCaptured = false;

function mouseClicked() {
  if (!mouseCaptured) {
    mouseCaptured = true;
    requestPointerLock();
  }
}

function drawSkyBox() {
  push();
  translate(cam.eyeX, cam.eyeY, cam.eyeZ);

  push();
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    translate(0, 0, -skyBoxSize / 2);
    fill(skyBoxColors[i]);
    plane(skyBoxSize, skyBoxSize);
    translate(0, 0, skyBoxSize / 2);
    rotateY(-90);
  }
  pop();

  push();
  rotateX(-90);
  translate(0, 0, -skyBoxSize / 2);
  fill(skyBoxColors[4]);
  plane(skyBoxSize, skyBoxSize);
  pop();
  push();
  rotateX(90);
  fill(skyBoxColors[5]);
  translate(0, 0, -skyBoxSize / 2);
  plane(skyBoxSize, skyBoxSize);
  pop();

  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
```

The experience isn't perfect on StackOverflow because it is not possible to capture the mouse given the iframe settings.